# Rewriting a script to use dd instead of mounting

Tags: linux, windows, sh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to rewrite a bash script to not use the mount command. I want to remove the mount command so I can run this using Windows Subsystem for Linux which currently does not support mounting.

This script is called after compiling some C code into a file called bootimg.
It takes a file mp3.img (a raw binary file), and somehow puts the new bootimg file as well as a filesys_img file into it, producing an updated mp3.img file.

Here is the original code.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -d /mnt/tmpmp3 ]; then
rmdir /mnt/tmpmp3
fi

if [ -d /tmp/mp3 ]; then
rm -rf /tmp/mp3
fi

mkdir /mnt/tmpmp3
mkdir /tmp/mp3
cp ./bootimg /tmp/mp3/
cp ./filesys_img /tmp/mp3/
cp ./mp3.img /tmp/mp3/
mount -o loop,offset=32256 /tmp/mp3/mp3.img /mnt/tmpmp3
cp -f /tmp/mp3/bootimg /mnt/tmpmp3/
cp -f /tmp/mp3/filesys_img /mnt/tmpmp3/
umount /mnt/tmpmp3
cp -f /tmp/mp3/mp3.img ./
rm -rf /tmp/mp3
rmdir /mnt/tmpmp3
```

I do not really understand how mounting the img file as a loopback device works.
I have been trying to replace mount with dd but have not yet succeeded.

How can I change this scipt to build the updated mp3.img file using dd (or something similar) instead of mounting it?

Comment: You can't simply use `dd` here. The file `mp3.img` is a partitioned disk image, with some sort of formatted file system in the first partition. The file system could one Linux's ext file systems, FAT32, NTFS, UDF or anything that's supported by Linux. The files `bootimg` and `filesys_img` are copied to that file system as ordinary files, updating the file system's root directory, allocation structures and other metadata accordingly. The `dd` command won't update this metadata. If it's a FAT formatted partition you might be able to use something like mtools.

Comment: Btw: sh is not bash

Comment: If the file system used is one of the ones Windows supports you might be able to get it to work by converting the `mp3.img` file to a VHD file, mounting it with `diskpart`, copying the files, and then umounting it and converting the VHD file back to a raw disk image.

Comment: @RossRidge might as well post all that as an answer :)

Comment: Thanks @RossRidge. The mp3.img file is actually an OS I'm working on for a course. The first part is a GRUB header I believe. Would you mind explaining how you can tell it is a partitioned disk image? Or how mounting it as a loopback device works? I will give your second comment a try and report back! :)

Comment: GRUB needs to be installed in some sort of file system, and it supports a wide variety of them, so you need to figure out what file system that is. That file system would be where you're copying the files `bootimg` and `filesys_img`. I can tell its a partitioned image because of the `offset=32256` option in the mount command.

Comment: Oh so it uses the offset argument to get to the second partition, which is where bootimg and filesys_img are copied into? That makes way more sense, thanks a ton!